# Latex, remove blanks between sections in a chapter

Tags: sectioning, blank-page

I am writing thesis with 10 chapters, each of them has multiple sections.

In Latex, I put each section in a separate file.

But, there are blank spaces between sections in each chapter in the pdf file.

how to remove the blank meanwhile still keeping each section in separate .tex file ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if by "blank spaces" you mean that each section starts on a new page, you are probably using `\include{...}` to load the files.  use `\input{...}` instead.  using separate files is a good approach, allowing you to shuffle things around and otherwise concentrate your efforts just where you're currently working.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Concur.  Also beware of leaving blank lines between the `\input{..}` commands.  This can also cause extra vertical space with the section commands.

Comment: @R.Schumacher assuming that file starts with \section, blank lines between the \input commands make no difference whatsoever. They are equiv to \par and multiple \par commands are the same as one (unless they are redefined)